# Parallelization with Numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to make some code run in parallel using Numba, but the results differ depending on whether the code is executed in parallel or not. I am not sure whether my problem simply cannot be parallelized the way I want to do it or whether I am making a mistake. This is the code:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit()
def add_to_img(image, i1, i2):
    image[np.int(i1), np.int(i2)] += 1


def iterate_over_indices(image, indices1, indices2):
    for i in nb.prange(len(indices1)): 
        add_to_img(image, indices1[i], indices2[i])


iterate_seq = nb.njit(iterate_over_indices)
iterate_par = nb.njit(iterate_over_indices, parallel=True)


for _ in range(5):
    image_seq = np.zeros((3, 3))
    image_par = np.zeros_like(image_seq)
    ind1 = np.random.uniform(0, image_seq.shape[0], size=1000)
    ind2 = np.random.uniform(0, image_seq.shape[1], size=1000)
    iterate_seq(image_seq, ind1, ind2)
    iterate_par(image_par, ind1, ind2)
    print(np.array_equal(image_seq, image_par))
```

Most of the times, `image_seq` is different from `image_par`. What is the reason for this? I am running on a machine with 4 physical cores and 8 threads.

Comment: This code should run. I also encountered this bug before (inplace manipulation of an array allocated outside the function which contains the parfor loop). If you allocate an output array in the function itself it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself, the problem occurs when 2 threads want to write to the same pixel `image[np.int(i1), np.int(i2)]` at the same time. This will result in only one write being registered. If no coordinate occurs twice, this problem does not occur.